# How to make my Opencart for visible only members

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I have installed Opencart for using an online catalog. So I have to make it visible only members. I have searched google and also stackoverflow. I have found some tips but they are for version 1.5 and not compatible via our version.

I have found two extensions and they for version 1.5 too.

I have tried .htacces and .htpasswd pair but without usefull solution.

I found this code.

But seems like the file is not exist in version 2(our opencart version)

```
// Check store ID against subdomain store id value
if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 123) {

    // Check customer isn't logged in
    if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) {

        // Redirect if route isn't account/login
        if(empty($this->request->get['route']) ||     $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') {
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
        }
   }
```

}

So;

how can apply this code for opencart 2 and on which file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are code for OC 2.0. Please add following code on catalog/controller/common/header.php inside `index()` function

```
 if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
       if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') {  

           $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
       }
    }
```

If you want to enable both register and login, then following:

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
       if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || ($this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login' && $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/register')) {  

           $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have insert that piece of code to enf of function seems like it doesnt affect.

Comment: @ikutluay you should insert inside `index()` function. Better first line of the `index()` function

Comment: Actaully after that message i have do that and now it is worked. I came here for accept as answer and say thank you too.

Comment: Actually i dont want to they can register themselves. Can i redirect url to special designed HTML only page.. It will says "this is a private section, you need and account. Call us from 999 99 99 and we will galdly create account for you"

Comment: I will try "$this->response->redirect('html page url" combination.

Comment: I found that this is gonna recursive loop. So back to first code is most suitable